# Change mousedown focus to a new div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here's my code:

```
function drawGridSquare(tableText)
        {
            gridSquare = document.getElementById('square');
            gridSquare.innerHTML = tableText;
            document.body.appendChild(gridSquare);
            gridSquare.style.display = 'block';
            gridSquare.style.top = e.pageY - gridSquare.offsetHeight + 1;
            gridSquare.style.left = e.pageX - gridSquare.offsetWidth/2;
            gridSquare.focus();
        }
```

This function is called on mousedown from a td element:

```
<td onmousedown="drawGridSquare('textData');">
```

This generates a pretty little square which uses jQuery draggable/droppable function. All I want to do is while the user's mouse is STILL pressed down, the focus would revert to the gridSquare that was created.

What are my options for this?

Comment: Do you mean that when the square pops up, you want to be able to drag i without having to release the mouse button and then mousdown on the square again?

Comment: No. I want to show the square, and leave the mousedown there while the user moves the square around. When let go, the draggable command from jQuery should be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as how I couldn't find a clear way to do this, my work around is as follows:

```
function drawGridSquare(tableText, cellPosition)
        {
            gridSquare = document.getElementById('square');
            gridSquare.innerHTML = tableText;
            document.body.appendChild(gridSquare);
            gridSquare.style.display = 'block';
            startPositionX = endPositionX = cellPosition;
            gridSquare.style.top = mouseY(event) - gridSquare.offsetHeight + 1;
            gridSquare.style.left = mouseX(event) - gridSquare.offsetWidth/2;
            squareReady = true;
        }

        function moveGridSquare()
        {
            if (squareReady)
            {
                squareIsMoving = true;
                characterWidth = 1;
                gridSquare = document.getElementById('square');
                gridSquare.style.top = mouseY(event) - gridSquare.offsetHeight + 1;
                gridSquare.style.left = mouseX(event) - gridSquare.offsetWidth/2;
            }
        }

function selectionEnd() {
    if (squareIsMoving)
            {
                //Code to DROP INTO THE GRID
                var dataStart = (Math.round((startPositionX) / characterWidth)) + 1;
                var dataLength = Math.abs((Math.round((endPositionX)/characterWidth)) - (Math.round((startPositionX) / characterWidth)));
                var data = dataStart + "," + dataLength + "," + theSelectedText;
                dropDone(data);

                //Set square to false
                squareIsMoving = false;
                squareReady=false;

                //Destroy the square
                document.getElementById('square').innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById('square').style.display = 'none';
            }
}
<body onmousemove="moveGridSquare();">
<div id="square" onmousedown="squareReady=true;moveTheSquare();" onmouseup="selectionEnd();" style="display:none;" ></div>
```

Comment: I am still looking for a direct method if possible.